# replacing characters in entire document JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have tried a number of different approaches to this but nothing is working. Right now I have:

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
    $(".page").click(function () {

        var html = $(document).html();

        html.replace("[", "<");

        alert("here");
    });


 });
```

This refuses to work. It will also not allow me to do anything how the Jquery exmaples go for instance

```
  $("[").replaceWith("<");
```

It seems to me that .replace is not even in jQuery even though a lot of examples seem to have it as part of query. Any suggestions? This is starting to frustrate me. I have tried passing in a particular div and it still refuses to work. Any ideas? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: How about explaining what you are trying to achieve instead of what isn't working?

Comment: I am trying to replace "[" with "<" inside the entire document

Comment: `html.replace` just updates the variable `html`, it doesn't update the DOM.  `$(document).html(html)`.

Comment: To set the document's html, you'd use something like `$(document).html( $(document).html().replace("[", "<") )`.

Comment: I would suggest NOT replacing the entire document html with new html. Instead, iterate over all text nodes and do the replace on each node using the regexp from the answer below. Or, use an existing tested plugin. There are several.

Comment: Example plugin: http://benalman.com/projects/jquery-replacetext-plugin/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
$(document.documentElement).html(function(i,val){
    return val.replace(/\[/g,'<');
});
```

[**document**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document) itself is not a `DOM Element`,you should use [**document.documentElement**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/document.documentElement) instead.

Comment: Whats up with the funky syntax? "/\[/g". If I have say %lbrack% for something like that, would it be return val.replace('%lbrack%','<'); ? Thanks a lot for the help btw!

Comment: @user1260028 `/[/g` is a Regular Expression, which matches all `[` symbols.  `replace('[','>')` will replace **only the first** `[` symbol,but `replace(/\[/g,'>')` **all** `[` symbols. About `%lbrack%` I can't say anything, I don't understand what is it, and what you want?

Comment: @user1260028 You should use `RegExp`s if you want to replace *all* matches,if you will pass `String`, *only the first* match will be replaced.

Comment: the %lbrack% is just a definition, it can be 12354123. Basically any point %lbrack% happens it gets replaced by "["

Comment: What is very strange, is that once I get both to be replaced, that block disapears. It only happens when I apply "<", other than that everything else works...

Comment: @user1260028 You should be  aware that replacing '<' could be dangerous. Consider this case '`[a`'.If you will replace `[` with `<`, you will have '`<a`', and browser will try to parse it as a `a` tag. Of course it can't parse it, because it will be an *invalid markup*. So instead of '<', you should use `&lt;`->`.replace(/\[/g,'&lt;')`, which is safe.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me that you are creating a variable from the html but not sending it back to the page:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    //EDIT:
    // $(".page").click(function () { changed to a bind type event handler to
    // prevent loss of interactivity. .on() requires jQuery 1.7+ I believe.
    $(".page").on('click', function () {   
           var htmlString = $('body').html();

            // To replace ALL occurrences you probably want to use a regular expression
            // htmlString.replace(/\[/g, "<");
            htmlString.replace("[", "<");


            //Validate the string is being manipulated
            alert(htmlString);

            // Overwrite the original html
            $('body').html(htmlString);
    });
});
```

Bear in mind I haven't tested this, but if I'm not mistaken the .html() method in jQuery is used to get/set not necessarily to do direct manipulation.

Comment: This will do do the job but will recreate the entire DOM, losing any interactivity you may have had previously

Comment: Very true. The click function should be changed to a binding event handler such as  $(".page").on('click', function (){}); to compensate for this. I'll update my post.

Comment: @user1260028 This will work if you call `htmlString.replace("[", "&lt;");` instead of the non-escaped version

Answer (score 0):

The line `html.replace("[", "<");` is not doing anything

`html` is a string, so you are replacing the string and not doing anything with the output.

```
var foo = html.replace(/\[/g, "<");
$(document).html(foo);
```