# text going blank once [ ] gets replaced by < >

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following code

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $(".page").on('click', function () {
            $("#ctl00_MainContent_dfComments").html(function (i, val) {
                return val.replace(/\]/g, '>');
            });
        });

        $(".page").on('click', function () {
            $("#ctl00_MainContent_dfComments").text(function (i, val) {
                return val.replace(/\[/g, "<");
            });
        });

    });
```

Which with the help of [replacing characters in entire document JQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11620038/replacing-characters-in-entire-document-jquery/11620269#comment15388479_11620269) works wonderfully. However, when the < bracket is inserted, the entire div goes blank. I can replace the [ with anything, but as soon as I put in < everything inside that div disappears. Any idea of what might be going on?

Yes, this is supposed to create a bold (kind of like a bb parser)

Comment: Can you show us a sample input that breaks for you?

Comment: Try replacing it with `&lt;` and `&gt;` for `<` and `>`. These are the HTML entities for those characters;

Comment: What's the problem you're trying to solve with this approach? I'm not convinced that you're doing the right thing (but then again, I don't know *why* you're doing it in the first place...). Also, why are you using `html()` in the first code snippet, and `text()` in the second..?

Comment: it doesn't really matter what I'm trying to do with this. Like I said, its kind of like a bb parser.

@sachleen &lt; doesn't seem to produce the < bracket while the &gt; works great for ">"...

Comment: Do not use this to create a 'bb code parser'.  It will open your site up to very trivial XSS attacks.

Comment: Wonderful, I am here to solve this problem not to debate over why this is security issue, I am well aware of the implications. However, thank you for pointing this out :) @DavidThomas that will give the text version of the brackets. however, I need to make the text bold when the brackets are replaced...

Comment: @user1260028, if you're holding a stick of dynamite and asking for help lighting a match, do not be surprised when someone points out that it's not a candle in your hand.

Comment: Thank you. However, is there a solution for this or will the browser decide to remove the block every time it detects an html tag creation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your second replace is using `.text()` instead of `.html()`.  As a side note, you can also combine the two event handlers.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
  $(".page").on('click', function () {
    $("#ctl00_MainContent_dfComments").html(function (i, val) {
      return val.replace(/\]/g, '>').replace(/\[/g, '<');
    });
  });
});​
```

Here it is in action: http://jsfiddle.net/pbnDP/8/

Pressing the button makes the text go bold.

The obvious security concerns are discussed in the comments on the main post.  Don't put this on a site where users can generate the content this is being run on.

Comment: Thank you for not being an ass and actually helping me out. Its inside a controlled environment so that's why we decided its ok.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your probably not ending up with Valid HTML and the DOM rendering the html is disposing of any invalid HTML for you.

Theres a few problems with your script - the first it that it promotes dangerous html, your appear not to be doing any form of sanity or blacklist/whitelist checking on the code.

The other issue is your manually naming ASP.NET IDs - this is bad since they can change. Use .ClientID instead.

Answer (score 1):

```
       $(".page").on('click', function () {
        $("#ctl00_MainContent_dfComments").html(function (i, val) {
            return val.replace(/\[/g, "<");
        });
    });
```

.html might work better then text, and also use class name or clientid to select elements with like John suggested in his answer , that  is not good to guess what the browser is going to change the id to.

Comment: did you try .html and then use  &gt;  instead?

Comment: yea it just gives me what .text does, just a >. I need the internal text to go bold...

Comment: can't you add a class for that?

Answer (score 0):

Pleas check your DOM again, seems like browser either detects the `<` `>` as html tag or html aint valid.

**Working version:** http://jsfiddle.net/pbnDP/

I do know in few programming world including Ruby there is somthing called `html_safe` you might want to use alongside this.

Hope it helps.